# How else, other than using kirchoff's laws, can this circuit be analysed?

Tags: circuit-analysis

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fC20tu.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>
Attaching simplified working to show I've worked it out already, however the answer didn't come easily and I'm struggling to improve on circuit analysis. Also, what textbooks are good for improving?[image]

Comment: You can look at using the [wye-delta transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Y-%CE%94_transform). But whatever you use (voltage divider rule, wye-delta transform, series and parallel combinations) is ultimately only proven valid by Kirchoff's laws. Is that okay or are you looking for something else?

Comment: As @ThePhoton has alluded to, it's just practice. Well done for working through it! The more you do, the quicker you'll become and you'll be able to spot the transformations by inspection, which reduces the grind substantially. Keep at it, not much more to add :)

Comment: I suppose I wanted to know if the other circuit analysis techniques could reach the answer more efficiently

Answer (score 1):

You can convert R3, R4 and R5 into an equivalent Y circuit, then just add all the resistances and use good old Ohm's law.

Answer (score 0):

Try Node-Voltage method or graph theory.
I suggest 'Electrical Circuits' (by james w. nilsson)